# When I exit Sublime, I get the message of "New file has been modified, save changes?"

Tags: sublimetext2

It used to be that when I exited sublime, it didn't prompt me. So, if I restarted sublime it would reload files as they were.

Now when I try to close Sublime I get a prompt saying "New file has been modified, save changes?" and it prompts me for a filename.

It never used to do that.

How can I put it back to the old behavior?

What is different now that might be causing that?

Comment: I recently had it again this time with the right hot exit line.. I closed one of the windows then the other one stopped saying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`), make sure you have the following:

```json
"hot_exit": true
```

This means that unsaved modifications and open files will be preserved and restored the next time you start the program, and there will be no prompt to save them when closing Sublime.